# How to force 'mkproject' (virtualenvwrapper) to use python3 as default?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've added the following lines to my bash, but `mkproject` keeps creating python 2.7 folders into the virtual env, therefore I still need to use `-p python3`, which I'd like to not have to do.

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

Comment: `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=virtualenv3` ?

Comment: how could I define "virtualenv3"?

Comment: To use `virtualenv` for both `python2` and `python3` you need two `virtualenv` scripts.  The first line of `virtualenv` is often either `#!/usr/bin/python2` or `#!/usr/bin/python3` (the entry script for virtualenv is surprisingly short).  Several distros actually make two packages `virtualenv2` and `virtaulenv3`.  But, since you're on a mac, you get that through `brew` i believe, therefore you can safely copy `virtualenv` -> `virtualenv3` and change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Oh yeah, you have a `/usr/bin/python3` soft link pointing to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3` right?  (I may be a little off on the PATH since i never used a mac).

Comment: Thanks, @grochmal! It has worked o/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`virtualenvwrapper` understands the `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` environment variable, you need to set it to the `virtualenv` appropriate to the python version you're using.  For example:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=virtualenv3
```

This is needed because `virtualenvwrapper` executes `virtualenv` as a shell script (without adding `python2` or `python3` in the front of the command).

This way the `virtualenv` script is executed with the interpreter defined in its shebang (`#!`).

Most Linux distros provide two packages: `virtualenv2` and `virtualenv3` each containing one script:

`virtualenv2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import virtualenv
virtualenv.main()
```

`virtualenv3`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import virtualenv
virtualenv.main()
```

On a Mac you use `brew` for the `python` installation.  Therefore there is nothing wrong with copying the `virtualenv` script into two instances: `vritualenv2` and `virtualenv3` and change the shebang to the correct python version.

(You need to install the `virtualenv` eggs, through `pip`, for each python version.)

Answer (score 1):

I defined an alias in the `.bashrc` file to overwrite the `mkproject` command to use python3 by default:

```
alias mkproject='mkproject --python=/usr/bin/python3'
```